# Does anyone have ideas about how to implement the scrolling effect as in the iPhone app Applauze in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, scroll

Does anyone have ideas about how to implement the scrolling effect as in the iPhone app Applauze in iOS? How to implement this event screen - scrolling effect with the images expanding on scroll up and contract on scroll down in ios.

Comment: i added one link you must try this one really helpful to you..

Comment: Hi Jitendra, thank you so much for your reply, I should be more specific. I want to achieve the same effect as in the events screen of applauze app. Can u plz check that app from app store.

Comment: you need to try Carousel library.

Comment: what you tried you need to add that .h and .m library into your project and i think there two delegate method two add in your code.

Comment: @JitendraDeore: yes i have added them. Cover flow Example can be achieved using carousel library. I have also customized it. But this is not the one which i need. I want all the images which are linear to expand gradually upwards on scroll up and contract on scroll down.Plz, check this link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/applauze/id608609424?mt=8 (first screenshot)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses `UICollectionView` (instead of `UITableView`):

https://github.com/syshen/SlipingSlide

iOS 7 has some similar exotic effects in it like the tabs in Safari and the passes in the PassBook interface.  I recommend you watch session 217 from WWDC 2013 for more information.